# Mulesoft MMC Deployment unreconciled

Tags: mule

We have a cluster server for MuleSoft. All the applications are deployed correctly and working perfectly but the deployments are showing in red on on-premise MMC.

Each deployment says "Deployment unreconciled" when hover over the deployment. Mule_ee.logs doesn't give anything specific. Where could I find the logs to see why is MMC giving this message.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Mule MMC you are using - we had the same issue where MuleSoft suggested to upgrade the MMC to the latest version ie 3.8.2. This seems to be a known bug in the MMC version 3.5.2.

The deployment showing red because of the following reasons -
- Servers are shown as down in MMC but they're up and running.
- Alerts for server down are triggered even though the server was never down.
- Any operation over the servers is throwing an error as they're detected as being down.
- Applications may appear as offline when they're actually deployed.

Most of the above listed problems are caused by problems in the network that communicates MMC with the Mule instances. MMC does a ping over the instances which is in charge of updating the servers statuses. In order to avoid the mentioned problems, the frequency of the ping can be changed so it allows the tweaking for a value that suits the current network.

In order to do this you need to the edit the file /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/applicationContext.xml and modify the bean with id="pinger" to include a new constructor argument of type int (last argument). The value will define the socket timeout of the server status call. Value is expressed in ms-

```
<bean id="pinger" class="com.mulesoft.mmc.heartbeat.Pinger"> 
  <constructor-arg ref="serverManager" /> 
  <constructor-arg ref="statusServiceAdaptor" /> 
  <constructor-arg ref="eventManager" /> 
  <constructor-arg ref="pingServerExecutor" /> 
  <constructor-arg type="int"><value>10000</value></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

After making this change, please restart MMC and check if the servers still experience the same problem.

Note: the default value of the ping is 1000 (one second) for MMC version 3.6.x and 5000 for MMC 3.7.x.

Regards, 
Sanjeet Pandey

Answer (score 0):

The yellow icon (for unreconciled) wait until it is deployed.

See documentation below
https://docs.mulesoft.com/tcat-server/v/7.1.0/deploying-applications